# How exactly does the == operator work in dart when comparing objects?

Tags: dart, operators

So the Dart API says this about the == operator:

> The equality operator.
>
> The default behavior for all Objects is to return true if and only if
> this object and other are the same object.
>
> Override this method to specify a different equality relation on a
> class. The overriding method must still be an equivalence relation.
> That is, it must be:
>
> Total: It must return a boolean for all arguments. It should never
> throw.
>
> Reflexive: For all objects `o, o == o` must be `true`.
>
> Symmetric: For all objects `o1` and `o2`, `o1 == o2` and `o2 == o1` must
> either both be `true`, or both be `false`.
>
> Transitive: For all objects `o1`, `o2`, and `o3`, if `o1 == o2` and `o2 == o3`
> are `true`, then `o1 == o3` must be `true`.
>
> The method should also be consistent over time, so whether two objects
> are equal should only change if at least one of the objects was
> modified.
>
> If a subclass overrides the equality operator, it should override the
> hashCode method as well to maintain consistency.

But how exactly does Dart check, if 2 Objects are the same?

> return true if and only if
> this object and other are the same object

could be understood as "checks if both objects are references to the same instance" which apparently isn't the case.

So lets say I have 2 instances of

```
class Car {
  int tires = 4;
  Color color = Colors.blue;
  int doors = 4;
}

Car carA = Car();
Car carB = Car();
```

From my understanding if I check `carA == carB`, Dart compares all properties of both instances by looping over them?

If thats the case, does it always drill down to primitives if, for example, some properties are non-primitive classes?

Thanks

Comment: "*could be understood as "checks if both objects are references to the same instance" which apparently isn't the case.*"  Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Good question. Guess I had a fundamentally wrong understanding of the operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Dart *does* "checks if both objects are references to the same instance". If you want to compare the properties you can override the == operator, for example:

```
class Car {
  int tires = 4;
  int doors = 4;

  @override
   bool operator ==(Object other) {
     return other is Car && this.tires == other.tires && this.doors == other.doors;
   } 
  @override
  int get hashCode => this.tires * this.doors;
}

void main() {
  Car carA = Car();
  Car carB = Car();
  print("equal ${carA==carB}");
  print("identical ${identical(carA,carB)}");
}
```

Now the cars are equal. Note that the function `identical()` does check for the same object.

The Dart Spec specifies that constant objects do check the properties, for example:

```
class ConstCar {
  final int tires = 4;
  final int doors = 4;
  const ConstCar();
}

void main() {
  ConstCar constCarA = const ConstCar();
  ConstCar constCarB = const ConstCar();
  print("equal ${constCarA==constCarB}");
  print("identical ${identical(constCarA,constCarB)}");
}
```

This returns true for `==` and `identical()`.

Comment: Okay just to be cristal clear. By default, comparing ```(ObjectA == ObjectB) ```is the same as saying ```identical(ObjectA,ObjectB)``` , so if they are references to the same instance. 

If I want the ```==``` operator to compare the objects by properties, I'd have to override the operator?

Comment: Yes, you would need to override `operator==` (and `hashCode`) if you want to compare properties.

Comment: And the package "Equatable" can help you do most of that.

Comment: It's not that constant objects check the properties when you call `==`. Rather, constant objects are canonicalized *when created*, so if you create constant objects in two places with the properties that are `identical` (not just equal), one of them is thrown away and the compiler uses the same object in both places (it "canonicalizes" one instance as the one representing all the equivalent ones).